# Why my ajax script doesn't work?

Tags: ajax

Take a look at:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <title>Récupération d'un contenu HTML en Jquery Ajax</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function recupTexte() {
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "data.xml" 
        })
          .done(function( texte ) {
            $('body').append( " : " + texte );
          });
    }

    setInterval(recupTexte, 1000);


    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

data.xml

```
test
```

When I go to my web browser Safari, I have "test" displayed, but when I edit my data.xml file manually to "changed", Safari continues to display "test" and no "changed". Why ? I don't understand...

So, just to say it, this code only works in safari, and in local. When I put it in a server, nothing is displayed....

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue due to caching of get request. Try disabling the cache using :

`$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });`

or inside your ajax call

`$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  //other options...
});`